# find maximum number from the collection of object

Tags: java, collections

Having collection object with id, level and role as attribute and i want to find the maximum level from the set

for example from the below `Assignment` table the maximum level is `13`. how i can find the maximum level from the `SET`

Assignment table :

```
Id      Level   role
259256  1       SYSTM_ADMN  
259257  9       APPRVR_LVL_4
259258  8       APPRVR_LVL_3
259259  10      APPRVR_LVL_5
259260  6       APPRVR_LVL_1
259261  13      INTRNL_RD_ONLY
259268  8       SYSTM_ADMN  
259269  10      SYSTM_ADMN  
259270  9       SYSTM_ADMN
```

following code has been written using `Java8`. But i want to run the code in Java6.

```
Assignment assignment =  Collections.max(assignmentset, Comparator.comparing(s -> s.getLevel()));
```

Comment: Which part do you need help with?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - how to get the maximum level `13` using java6. not java8

Comment: There were no Lambda-Expressions back in Java6, you have to use an anonymous inner class instead

Comment: @Karthikeyan You should use a for loop instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that, using just a loop:

```
public Assignment getMaxAssignmentFromCollection(Collection collection) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    Assignment maxAssignment = null;
    for(Assignment element: collection) {
        if(element.getLevel() > max) {
            max = element.getLevel();
            maxAssignment = element;
        }
    }
    return maxAssignment;
}
```

And then use it:

`Assignment maxAssignment = getMaxAssignmentFromCollection(assignmentSet);`

Answer (score 1):

Stream operators doesn't work in Java 6. They appear in Java 8. So you need only to go loop  for each element getting the max value. That is the only to making this work.